# Do VirtualBox snapshots take up space?

Tags: virtualbox, snapshot

When I remove a snapshot, it just says 'Merging differencing image'. I don't know how much room each snapshot is taking. It's certainly not copying everything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you take a snapshot, VirtualBox stops writing to the .vdi and starts writing to the snapshot file. When you merge, it merges the snapshot file into the original .vdi and you're left with the original .vdi plus the changes.

To answer the question explicitly, yes.

Comment: It must be VERY little space because I just removed 10+ snapshots and didn't notice a difference on my drive's panel

Comment: Like I said, it's some sort of (probably optimized) diff. But I've blue screened my machine before writing to snapshots, filling my 120 GB OS drive (by default VirtualBox is configured to use AppData to store its stuff), they can definitely reach gigabytes in size.

Comment: I think snapshoot in this page can explain something: 

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?p=29272#29272

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they do, and apparently snapshotting also increases disk space usage compared to just a single logical disk.

Check out this excellent blog post on how to merge snapshots and compact them to reduce disk space used: http://srackham.wordpress.com/2010/06/17/merging-and-compacting-virtualbox-snapshots/